# @Html.TextAreaFor() always validated as required even if annotated as nullable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

Why is a TextAreaFor is always validated as required in mvc even if annotated with the following:

```
public class DepartmentViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Department Name")]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Remarks")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true), 
     DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cost Center")]
    public int ? CostCenterId { get; set; }
}
```

and in the View part I use this:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Remarks, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 col-sm-12" })
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Remarks, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Remarks, new { @class = "form-control", style = "resize: none;", @rows = 10 })
                    </div>
</div>
```

if i change it to be **TextBoxFor** everything is working. I want to tag the remarks to be optional but using **TextAreaFor** it is always Required.

Comment: Just remove the `[Required]` and `[DisplayFormat]` attributes (and the `[DataType]` attribute since thats only applicable if you use `EditorFor()`)

Comment: i've already done that but the result is still the same

Comment: The model will not be invalid if you remove those attributes. If it is, then is other code you have not show us that's causing the problem.

Comment: how can i accept your comment as an answer..?? post it as answer coz it solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `[Required]` and `[DisplayFormat]` attributes. You can also remove the `[DataType]` attribute since that is only applicable if using `@Html.EditorFor()`. Your property just needs to be

```
[Display(Name = "Remarks")]
public string Remarks { get; set; }
```

although even the `[Display]` attribute is not required since its the same as the property name.

Comment: That should not be needed :)

Comment: Im doing this kind of annotation for so long but i've just been in this problem just now